# Мобильная версия сайта

Tags: css3, веб-программирование, javascript, html5, mobile-web

Всем привет!

Совсем недавно у меня возник очередной вопрос.

Недавно я закончил курс по программированию на HTML5 & CSS3. Вот у меня есть знания, но я просто понятия не имею, как их применять. Профессиональные программисты и хорошо обосновавшиеся веб-дизайнеры говорят, что сначала нужно сделать мобильную версию сайта, а потом делать, скажем так, полную версию. Представим себе, что у нас уже есть домен - http://example.ru. Что нужно сделать, чтобы при открытии сайта по такой ссылке - http://m.example.ru - открывалась мобильная версия этого сайта? У меня была мысль по поводу того, что нужен JavaScript, но я могу ошибаться.

Прошу вашей помощи. Наведите меня на правильный путь.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте css [@ media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: @knes Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта:
1. Создать субдомен (поддомен) и создать на нем полностю сайт с нуля, но для мобилок.
2. Создать субдомен (поддомен) и перенаправить его на основной сайт, а там програмно получить значение поддомена и выдавать контент, который нужен.

Если нету нужды в поддомене (м.сайт.ру), посмотрите в сторону адаптивности. И на популярные CSS фреймворки, такие как [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Вы тогда сможете получить один сайт + одну верстку, которая будет одинаково хороша на всех устройствах.

Comment: фуу, бутстрап...

Comment: @mountpoint Bootstrap не так плох, как может казаться, но все же он бывает жетко не удобен.

Comment: @myvzar Спасибо